# SSRS Expression for "Items due this week" using date and time functions

Tags: datetime, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

If I have a couple items due this week (dueDate field) how can I get a count of those?

I currently have it as "Items due within a week (7 days)" but I want to get more specific. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using a Report table item to display your data.

In your Report Table item footer add an expression to count how many items are overdue.

```
=SUM(IIf(Fields!DateField.Value < "2012-05-14", 1, 0))
```

The above example has fixed value "2012-05-14" but you can make this dynamics by using parameter or date functions

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to return just those records you could use a WHERE Clause in the SQL Statement such as

```
WHERE 
DATEPART(week,duedate) = DATEPART(week,getdate()) AND
DATEPART(yyyy, duedate) = DATEPART(yyyy,getdate())
```

This simply checks that the year and week number in the dueDate field match that of the current system date.